# How to parallelize while loops?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, parallel-processing

```
iter <- 1000
myvec <- c()
while(is.null(myvec) || nrow(myvec) <= iter){
 x = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
 if(sum(x) > 2.5){
    myvec <- rbind(myvec, x)
 }
}
```

I want to parallelize the above while loop, where I keep iterating until I have a total of `iter = 1000` entries in `myvec`. I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121109/parallel-while-loop-in-r) post here, but I don't think the answer there is applicable to my example.

Comment: Should be sd = 1 instead of sigma = 1 (line 4)?

Comment: This loop is fairly hard to effectively parallelise in R because of the data dependency in the loop condition but you can make your existing code a lot more efficient by (a) not repeatedly calling `rbind` which makes your algorithm asymptotically slower, and (b) generating larger matrices of normally distributed random numbers and finding the first row for which the condition no longer holds. Then cut off the remaining rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you don't need to parallelize the while loop. You can vectorize your operations over `x` like below

```
iter <- 1000
myvec <- c()
while (is.null(myvec) || nrow(myvec) <= iter) {
  x <- matrix(rnorm(iter * 10, mean = 0, sd = 1), ncol = 10)
  myvec <- rbind(myvec, subset(x, rowSums(x) > 2.5))
}
myvec <- head(myvec, iter)
```

or

```
iter <- 1000
myvec <- list()
nl <- 0
while (nl < iter) {
  x <- matrix(rnorm(iter * 10, mean = 0, sd = 1), ncol = 10)
  v <- subset(x, rowSums(x) > 2.5)
  nl <- nl + nrow(v)
  myvec[[length(myvec) + 1]] <- v
}
myvec <- head(do.call(rbind, myvec), iter)
```

which would be much faster even if you have large `iter`, I believe.

Comment: What does using the future contribute here? The value isn’t (and can’t be!) calculated lazily. And, at any rate, the calculation of the values of `x` isn’t the slow part here — the repeated `rbind`ing is. With your solution (minus the future) that’s solved.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think `future` is necessary or able to speed up too much. I just put it here in case OP doesn't know how to rewrite the existing answer from the link to this specific question. Anyway, I provided another base R option, which is much faster.

Comment: Author of future here: the use for futures here, as in `myvec[[k]] %<-% x`, will take _the value of `x` as calculated in the main R session_, export it to the parallel worker, which then will return its value.  Note how it does _not_ perform any calculations in parallel.  So, unfortunately this won't work.  It effectively does what `myvec[[k]] <- x` does, but much less efficient. I suggest that you drop the future example code so that no one comes here in the future and thinks that how it can be done.

Comment: @HenrikB Thanks for your comment. I agree to remove the answer with `future` :)